# Google Webmaster Tools -> URL-Parameter after Migration from Magento

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url, search-results, url-parameters

After migrating from magento to a different e-commerce system I can find lots of URL-Parameters with millions of monitored sites:

[image]

Is it safe to reset those? Or better leave them? We already had a recent drop in our SERP-Ranking due to a lower amount of indexed pages. I really wanna avoid any further deranking but also wanna avoid crawling errors

Answer (score 1):

What the bots dislike most are duplicates. The first thing I'd do is add: `<link rel="canonical" ... />` links in the `<head>` section of your various e-commerce pages and of course review and update your [sitemaps.xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) file.

See: [About rel="canonical"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

Comment: yeah i know we got that covered. duplicate content was the first thing we wanted to avoid. i'm just afraid that reseting the URL-Parameters will lead google to delete old indexed pages and lower our page rank.

Comment: If that's your concern, it seems like the way to fight that is with 302 permanent redirects for key, high PageRank pages.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with my friend @artlung - bots dislike duplicates and that's why I would also use [redirect 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf) to prevent duplicates